# What type of join should I use?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My join knowledge is terrible, I can't find the correct one for this. I want to join the two tables on the TableA.userID and the TableB.otherID to match the desired output. I don't have any foreign or primary keys set on the tables. What should I be using here?

```
TableA:
+--------+--------+---------+
| userID | field1 | field2  |
+--------+--------+---------+

TableB:
+--------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| userID | otherID  | myData1 | myData2 | myData3 | 
+--------+----------+---------+---------+---------+

Desired Output:
+--------+----------+---------+---------+---------+--------+--------+
| userID | otherID  | myData1 | myData2 | myData3 | field1 | field2 |
+--------+----------+---------+---------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: It is a question of NULLs. Do you have any NULL userIDs? If not use an inner join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select a.userID, b.otherID, b.myData1, b.myData2, b.myData3, a.field1, a.field1
from TableA a
inner join TableB b
on a.userID = b.otherID
```

I recommend adding indexes on TableA.userID and TableB.otherID.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i am misunderstanding the question but couldn't you just use a simple INNER JOIN, assuming both USERID and OTHERID are the same datatype and you don't need to perform any data conversions.

```
SELECT A.userID, B.otherID, B.myData, B.myData2, B.myData3, A.field1, A.field2
FROM   TableA as A
       INNER JOIN TableB as B
       ON A.UserId = B.OtherId
```